# How to write an ini file with if conditions

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I want to write an ini file with if else conditions that i parse it with ConfigParser in python.

How to use if and Else statements in ini File ??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking...

What you're probably looking to do is something like this:

Set the value of the conditions in the INI file...

```
[section_1]
condition_a = true
condition_b = false
condition_c = false
```

Read in the conditions' boolean values using *getboolean()*...

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('my_file.ini')

if config.getboolean('section_1', 'condition_a'):
    # Run your first conditional code
if config.getboolean('section_1', 'condition_b'):
    # Run your second conditional code
if config.getboolean('section_1', 'condition_c'):
    # Run your third conditional code
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your comments but My requirement is whether i can use if -else directly in INI file.Like Below Example..                                                  :`if condition:
[section_1]
condition_a
condition_b
condition_c

else

[section_2]
condition_d
[section_1]
condition_a
condition_b
condition_c
`

Comment: I don't think you're using INI files correctly. Can you give some more context.

Comment: You can't use if-then-else in the INI file itself because is not part of the INI format. INI, as posted, is a simple text file, but the format is unique and some parsers know how to deal with it. Any wrong syntax it can lead to errors. Seems that you don't need ini, you can try another format, for example libconfig can parse a lot of formats, you might want to try that.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, XSLT (XML) might be useful. It supports _if-else_ conditions. See: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp)