# How to do conditional logging on file with .ini extension?

Tags: python, logging, ini

I want to keep program's logs on logs.log file.
I have logging.ini file that keeps the config of logging.

```
[logging]
logging=false

[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler



[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p
```

I want to change if logging=true ;

```
class = FileHandler
args=('logs.log',)
```

How can i do that ?
Thanks,

Comment: your question is not very clear, so maybe the following two questions will help. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437693/how-to-write-an-ini-file-with-if-conditions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418741/modifying-python-variables-based-on-config-file-entries)

Comment: i want to read ini files class and arg keys according to logging value